# Disable requires_auth decorator from fastapi-microsoft-identity

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, mocking, fastapi, python-unittest

I am using https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-microsoft-identity/ package for AD Azure authorization using `requires_auth` decorator. From my tests would like to avoid the authorization process but I cannot disable this decorator always returns 401.

this is the following code I am using from my test

```
def mock_decorator(*args, **kwargs) :
    def decorator(f)
    wraps(f)
    def requires_auth(*args, **kwargs):
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return requires_auth


patch('fastapi_microsoft_identity.requires_auth', mock_decorator).start()

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    with TestClient(api) as client:
        yield client

 def test_api_endpoint(client):
     response = client.get("/api/weather/london")
     assert response.status_code == 200
```

Since I am patching auth decorator should return 200 status code, instead, I am getting 401 UnAuthorized

The following code from  api

```
@router.get('/api/weather/{city}')
@requires_auth
async def weather(request: Request, loc: Location = Depends(), units: Optional[str] = 'metric'):
    try:
        validate_scope(expected_scope, request)
        return await openweather_service.get_report_async(loc.city, loc.state, loc.country, units)
    except AuthError as ae:
        return fastapi.Response(content=ae.error_msg, status_code=ae.status_code)
    except ValidationError as ve:
        return fastapi.Response(content=ve.error_msg, status_code=ve.status_code)
    except Exception as x:
        return fastapi.Response(content=str(x), status_code=500)
```

please help what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- You can't really bypass a decorator but can circumnavigate it if in its implementation it uses `@wrap()` in the code.
- Now `@ require_auth` does use a `@wrap` in its implementation so we can circumnavigate the decorator by calling the original function in this case ‘weather’ function as:-
  `weather.__wrapped__()`
  instead of the usual way of calling the function.
- The `__wrapped__`  method basically has reference to the original function instead of the decorator.
- Here I created a small API which basically returns two strings now here I have called the weather function without the `.__wrapped__`

```
# main.py

from fastapi_microsoft_identity import requires_auth, validate_scope, AuthError
import fastapi


from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@requires_auth
async def weather()   :
    return False
    

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    if await weather.() :
        return {"Decorator is working and not allowing the function f() to work "}
    else :
        return {"Decorator is disabled"}
```

[image]

Here the `weather ()` doesn’t get executed that is why the string “Decorator is working and not allowing the function f() to work” is returned but in your  case it is giving unauthorize error
But now when I call it using wrapped

```
# main.py

from fastapi_microsoft_identity import requires_auth, validate_scope, AuthError
import fastapi


from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@requires_auth
async def weather()   :
    return False
    

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    if await weather.__wrapped__() :
        return {"Decorator is working and not allowing the function f() to work "}
    else :
        return {"Decorator is disabled"}
```

[image]

Now that I have used the`,__wrapped__` while calling the weather function it is being executed directly circumnavigating the decorator

So if you don’t want the `require@auth`to work call the weather function like this `weather.__wrapped__(<arguments>)`

Refer this python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#:%7E:text=The%20original%20underlying%20function%20is%20accessible%20through%20the,the%20cache%20or%20until%20the%20cache%20is%20cleared.)  on wrapper method and this gihub [repo](https://github.com/425show/fastapi_microsoft_identity/blob/main/fastapi_microsoft_identity/auth_service.py) on require_auth.